# Algorithm to express elements of a matrix as a vector

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

**Statement of Problem:**

1. I have an array `M` with `m` rows and `n` columns.  The array `M` is filled with non-zero elements.
2. I also have a vector `t` with `n` elements, and a vector `omega`
       with `m` elements.
3. The elements of `t` correspond to the columns of matrix `M`.
4. The elements of `omega` correspond to the rows of matrix `M`.

**Goal of Algorithm:**

Define `chi` as the multiplication of vector `t` and `omega`.  *I need to obtain a 1D vector `a`, where each element of `a` is a function of `chi`.*

Each element of `chi` is unique (i.e. every element is different).

Using mathematics notation, this can be expressed as `a(chi)`

Each element of vector `a` corresponds to an element or elements of `M`.

**Matlab code:**

Here is a code snippet showing how the vectors `t` and `omega` are generated.  The matrix `M` is pre-existing.

```
[m,n] = size(M);
t = linspace(0,5,n);
omega = linspace(0,628,m);
```

**Conceptual Diagram:**

**This appears to be a type of integration (if this is the right word for it) along constant chi.**

[image: Diagram]

**Reference:**

[Link to reference](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING#page=208)

The algorithm is not explicitly stated in the reference.  I only wish that this algorithm was described in a manner reminiscent of computer science textbooks!

Looking at Figure 11.5, the matrix M is Figure 11.5(a).  The goal is to find an algorithm to convert Figure 11.5(a) into 11.5(b).

It appears that the algorithm is a type of integration (averaging, perhaps?) along constant `chi`.

Comment: From the link you have given, I think that to get from figure 11.5(a) to 11.5(b) you should make something called Gabor Transform. Read the page 190 of the book you shared with us. This algorithm seems to be pretty involved. I suggest you try to understand it, and also to consult related pages in the matlab webpage: (1) search 'gabor transform matlab' in google. (2) check the webpage, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5237-2d-gabor-filterver123 . This link from Matlab 'file exchange' is promising (4/5 stars from voters)! I think it could work pretty fast for you! Good luck!

Comment: @jespestana: Yes, I've written my own version of the Gabor transform, and I've used it to generate something similar to Figure 11.5(a), which is a 2D matrix as a 2D spectrum.  Now that the Gabor transform has been calculated, the 2D spectrum needs to be collapsed into a 1D spectrum as noted on pg. 190.  I still don't know if the spectral collapsing can be done with the Gabor transform.

Comment: I think you should try to find another book. I do not understand why they use A(chi) without describing it... Anyway, if you want to integrate using the trapezoidal rule check the function trapz(t,y). Sorry, but I do not know anything about the Gabor transform, let alone about collapsing the data. If you could give us the exact formula you want to implement, it would be easier for us to suggest a solution.

Comment: I agree completely with you.  If I had the exact formula or even a nice algorithm listing, it would be much easier.  I will try to experiment some more and see where this leads me.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to use two separate loops.  The outer loop is over the `chi` variable values, whereas the inner loop is over the `i` variable values.  Referring to the above diagram in the original question, the `i` variable corresponds to the x-axis (time), and the `j` variable corresponds to the y-axis (frequency). Assuming that the `chi`, `i`, and `j` variables can take on any real number, [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) is then used to find an amplitude corresponding to an element in matrix `M`.  The integration is just an averaging over elements of `M`.

The following code snippet provides an overview of the basic algorithm to express elements of a matrix as a vector using the spectral collapsing from 2D to 1D.  I can't find any reference for this, but it is a solution that works for me.

```
% Amp = amplitude vector corresponding to Figure 11.5(b) in book reference
% M = matrix corresponding to the absolute value of the complex Gabor transform 
% matrix in Figure 11.5(a) in book reference
% Nchi = number of chi in chi vector
% prod = product of timestep and frequency step
% dt = time step
% domega = frequency step
% omega_max = maximum angular frequency
% i = time array element along x-axis
% j = frequency array element along y-axis
% current_i = current time array element in loop
% current_j = current frequency array element in loop
% Nchi = number of chi
% Nivar = number of i variables
% ivar = i variable vector

% calculate for chi = 0, which only occurs when
% t = 0 and omega = 0, at i = 1
av0 = mean( M(1,:) );           
av1 = mean( M(2:end,1) );       
av2 = mean( [av0 av1] );    
Amp(1) = av2;                  

% av_val holds the sum of all values that have been averaged
av_val_sum = 0;

% loop for rest of chi 
for ccnt = 2:Nchi                       % 2:Nchi

    av_val_sum = 0;                     % reset av_val_sum 
    current_chi = chi( ccnt );          % current value of chi

    % loop over i vector
    for icnt = 1:Nivar                  % 1:Nivar

        current_i = ivar( icnt );
        current_j = (current_chi / (prod * (current_i - 1))) + 1;
        current_t = dt * (current_i - 1);
        current_omega = domega * (current_j - 1);

        % values out of range
        if(current_omega > omega_max)
            continue;
        end

        % use bilinear interpolation to find an amplitude
        % at current_t and current_omega from matrix M
        % f_x_y is the bilinear interpolated amplitude

        % Insert bilinear interpolation code here

        % add to running sum
        av_val_sum = av_val_sum + f_x_y;
    end % icnt loop

        % compute the average over all i
        av = av_val_sum / Nivar;

        % assign the average to Amp
        Amp(ccnt) = av;

end % ccnt loop
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) is the matlab function you need to use.  As noted in the link:

> `B = reshape(A,siz)` returns an n-dimensional array with the same elements as A, but reshaped to `siz`, a vector representing the dimensions of the reshaped array.

That is, create a vector `siz` with the number `m*n` in it, and say `A = reshape(P,siz)`, where P is the product of vectors t and ω; or perhaps say something like `A = reshape(t*ω,[m*n])`.  (I don't have matlab here, or would run a test to see if I have the product the right way around.)  Note, the link does not show an example with one number (instead of several) after the matrix parameter to `reshape`, but I would expect from the description that `A = reshape(t*ω,m*n)` might also work.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What I don't understand is how to pull elements from the matrix `M` such that `a(chi)` is unique.  That is, each element in `a(chi)` is taken from `M`.  Perhaps this is a type of integration along constant `chi`?

Comment: I took “Define chi as the multiplication of vector t and omega” in the question to mean that chi is the matrix product of two vectors, with the matrix then linearized into a vector.  If P is that product, P(i,j) = omega(i)*t(j).  If omega and t are created by linspace(0,p,m) and linspace(0,q,n) then P(i,j) = i*j*p*q/(m*n), which will have one value per i*j value; eg, P(1,12) = P(2,6) = P(6,2) = P(3,4) = P(4,3), which apparently is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a pseudocode or a link to the algorithm you want to implement. From what I could understood I have developed the following code anyway:

```
M = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]' % easy test M matrix
a = reshape(M, prod(size(M)), 1)    % convert M to vector 'a' with reshape command

[m,n] = size(M);                    % Your sample code
t = linspace(0,5,n);                % Your sample code
omega = linspace(0,628,m);          % Your sample code 

for i=1:length(t)
    for j=1:length(omega)           % Acces a(chi) in the desired order
        chi = length(omega)*(i-1)+j;
        t(i)                        % related t value
        omega(j)                    % related omega value
        a(chi)                      % related a(chi) value
    end
end
```

As you can see, I also think that the reshape() function is the solution to your problems. I hope that this code helps,

Comment: Thanks, jespestana; this is very much appreciated!  Questions: Is this a type of integration along constant chi?  Is there a unique mapping between a given `chi` and the elements of the matrix?  I will update my question above with a link to a reference.

Comment: *Is there a unique mapping between a given chi and the elements of the matrix?* The mapping is unique in the sense that for each value of chi inside the double for loop you access online one value of the 'M' matrix (now converted to 'a' vector)
*Is this a type of integration along constant chi?* Nope, I am only showing with an easy example how the mapping of chi to M is unique. I do not quite understand the physics behind your definition of chi = t*omega.
I am going to check the reference.

Comment: Thanks, jespestana. That reference has given me headaches, and any help you can offer is much appreciated.  In the reference, chi is the product of time and frequency.  The matrix as Figure 11.5(a) is plotted in a similar fashion to an `imagesc()` plot in Matlab.  The |Amplitude| corresponds to each element in the 2D matrix.  The goal is to collapse the 2D matrix into a 1D matrix, supposedly by an integration along constant chi.

Comment: Check my comment to your original post. I think you need to make a thing called "Gabor Transform" (check page 190 from the link you shared with us). A good place to look is either directly in matlab functions (I have made a fast search and I think that such a function does not exist), and also check the matlab file exchange (matlab users share functions through the file exchange, it is a really good place to search for matlab functions implemented by others).

Comment: Yes - I found it very challenging to implement my own version of the Gabor transform.  Thanks for the helpful links.

Comment: I have just noticed that there is a specific stackexchange forum for statistical and data anylisis. It is called Cross Validated, check it at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ . Maybe there are people there that now about this Gabor Transform and collapse algorithm.